# what does "post" stand for in sem_post?

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm new to C, sorry if my question sounds dumb.
We know that `sem_post` function unlock a semaphore, but why it is called in this way, isn't it more suitable to be called `sem_unlock`, I don't think "post" has a meaning of "unlock"?

Comment: You can post another unit to a semaphore when it's count is already greater than zero whereas, classically, you cannot unlock a door that is already unlocked.  'post' is fine - you can post multiple letters in a postbox, and the recipient gets all of them and needs to open them one-by-one.

Comment: Using it as a "lock" is just one of many different ways in which a semaphore can be used. IMO, the best way to think about a semaphore is to think of it as a _blocking queue_ of informationless _tokens._  The `sem_post` method adds a token to the queue, and the `sem_wait` method waits _if necessary_ until the queue contains at least one token, and then it removes one token from the queue before it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always thought of it as the word "post", as in "post a message", since you're effectively sending a signal to some process waiting to run, or possibly about to want to run.

Wikipedia attempts to explain the original `V` (post) and `P` (wait) operation names; apparently, they're one-letter abbreviations for Dutch words but we're not really sure which words. [Read it here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)#Operation_names), although it probably doesn't help much with the choice of English words.

Comment: Passeren/vrijgeven seems to be the best explanation. Passeren is a bit ambiguous, (and maybe too arcane, even in Dutch). Post/Release would probably be the best English metaphores. Another translation for P (passereen) would be "pass though, go ahead." (like in a checkpoint)

Comment: @wildplasser: but "P" is "wait", not "post". If "passereen" works for both of those, it's certainly ambiguous. What's really wanted is "allow someone to pass", which is not easy to resume in a single short word in any language I know. (`sem_goforit` is probably not a winning suggestion.)

Comment: Maybe "request to pass" would be better, then. (could it block? Yes: it could!) Perhaps the RFC IAC wording is simpler (DO/DONT/WILL/WONT)

Comment: 'you're effectively sending a signal to some process waiting to run' well, not really.  You are posting a unit to the semaphore whether there is a waiting thread/process or not, just like posting a note through a letterbox - even if there is nobody home when you post it, it will sit there until someone picks it up, along with any other letters posted, maybe by others.  This is in contrast to unlocking the door - if someone finds the door unlocked, the don't know how many times an unlock attempt was made, only that there was at least one.

Comment: @martin: so you agree that it's "post" as in "post a message" :-) I'll work on the wording of the message's receiver.